# how to fix mac'os problem with jubula autagent "autagent quit unexpectedly"?

Tags: eclipse, macos, jubula

I'm using jubula to automate a javafx application on mac OS but autagent can not run and it says 'autagent quit unexpectedly'.
can anyone have an idea about how to solve this problem on mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Jubula and Mac[1].If you have more Information please provide them in the eclipse Bug ticket. But there is no real need to start the external AUT agent anymore. The testexec, client API and Jubula can start an embedded Agent which is than be used for the test execution.

[1] http://eclip.se/525658

Comment: when starting the an embedded autAgent an error occurred "5009: AUT start failed:No valid Java binary found. Check given JRE binary. "

Comment: It seems that your given Application is not correctly set up in the Jubula AUT configuration.

Comment: i solved this issue. It was on the java folder. Thx